# Tools for Converting an Existing Website Design to a WordPress Template?

Tags: templates

I know how to do it manually, but is there any tool to help me with that?

Comment: Short answer: no.  You'll have to do it manually.

Comment: *@Jader Dias* - Afraid I have to agree with @EAMann on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free and good step by step tutorial with video.

**How To Convert an XHTML Website Template into a WordPress Theme**

http://www.jonbishop.com/2010/03/convert-html-wordpress/

There are many tools on market which claims to PSD/Xhtml 2 Wordpress

http://www.divine-project.com/

http://www.artisteer.com/

http://www.artisteer.com/

but coding manually is the best way. No quick way to get custom and great themes.

Answer (score 2):

This task could vary from rather simple to extremely difficult depending on the site you wish to convert over. Unfortunately there isn't a tool that will do the work for you. This task involves studying the WordPress codex in detail and inquiring as much as possible with other experienced developers.

It's a rather intimidating task, but the more time you spend in the documentation, the less intimidating the giant appears. I've been running myself over the coals for about a month now, and am working on my third conversion this week. The first two were terrifying, but they've been getting easier and easier.

Roll up your sleeves, and get ready for some serious studying!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Theme Framework like Genesis or WP Framework  if you want to don't want to write code from scatch every time you want to convert another design to a Wordpress Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug > Edit HTML > Strip out the content then save as source. You can then just drop in your WP snippets. At the very least, you'll have a starting point. I wouldn't recommend this method for a paying client, but it's quick and dirty and can be done.

Comment: Is there a formal and more defined process of what to do if you have the xHTML ready?

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastest way is by using http://wpsiteconvertor.com/, it's fast and you can convert unlimited websites which are all practically WordPress theme depository compatible. It creates a very proper WordPress theme in like a minute.